# Distribution of a composition of convergent sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

There are two convergent in probability sequences of random variables $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$, defined over a metric space $X$. From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573324/composition-of-convergent-sequences-of-continuous-functions) we know that under uniform continuity of $f$, the composition of sequences is convergent in probability as well, i.e. $f_n(g_n) \to f(g)$.

Is it true that

$$
\sqrt{n}(f_n(g_n) - f(g)) \to N\left(0, \mathbb{E}\left(f(g) - \mathbb{E}f(g)\right)^2\right)
$$

In particular, should there be no impact from a possible dependence between $f_n$ and $g_n$ on variance?

Comment: What are your assumptions? It is false that, if $h_n \rightarrow h$, then $\sqrt{n}(h_n-h) \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: I guess this is the link that I am missing between convergence in probability and CLT. What assumptions are needed for the CLT to hold in this case?

Comment: For example, let $f_{n} \equiv 0$ and $g_n \equiv 0$. In this case, $\sqrt{n}(f_n(g_n)-f(g)) \equiv 0$. I think that there is no general answer. However, the usual conditions in order to obtain a CLT, is to impose that $g_{n}$ is some kind of sample average. Or you can simply impose that $g$ has normal distribution.

Comment: Can I ask what line of argument you would use with $g$ having a normal distribution? Indeed, $g_n$ is the sample average in my setup. Actually, both $f_n$ and $g_n$ are empirical measures.

Comment: In this case, check the delta method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method